# Tensorflow: Determinism of AdamOptimizer when running in CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my application I optimize a neural network using the apply_gradient() and the AdamOptimizer. I noticed that I cannot reproduce the results exactly every time I run my application and it is required in order to compare results. While searching for similar issues I noticed that the issue of non-determinism can be encountered when Tensorflow runs in GPU, but my problem arises even in CPU.

I simplified my code and I think that the problem is the apply_gradients, but I am not sure because I am not experienced with tensorflow. The following code trains a neural network with random data (with a properly seeded numpy of course), and writes the network's parameters on a log file. If you run the program twice you will notice substantial differences in the net's params between different runs of the program, even though the training data are the same.

I use Tensorflow 1.11.0

Why this is happening? Is it probably due to arithmetic precision errors or am I doing something wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import logging
import sys
import math
import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Just configure logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.debug('Python version: %s', sys.version)
    logging.debug('Tensorflow version: %s', tf.__version__)
    logging.debug('Date time: %s', datetime.datetime.now())

    # Seed everything
    randomseed = 999
    np.random.seed(randomseed)
    tf.set_random_seed(randomseed)

    # Create a Neural Network
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, 10])
    hidden_dims = [100, 200]
    net = inputs
    for dim in hidden_dims:
        weight_initializer = tf.initializers.random_uniform(minval= - 1 / math.sqrt(10), maxval = 1 / math.sqrt(10))
        net = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net, units=dim, kernel_initializer=weight_initializer, bias_initializer=weight_initializer)
        net = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=net)
        net = tf.nn.relu(net)
    weight_initializer = tf.initializers.random_uniform(minval=-3e-3, maxval=3e-3)
    net = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net, units=20, kernel_initializer= weight_initializer, bias_initializer= weight_initializer)
    out = tf.nn.tanh(net)
    net_params = tf.trainable_variables()

    # Define some gradient ops
    grad = tf.gradients(out, net_params)
    gradients = list(map(lambda x: tf.div(x, 10), grad))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).apply_gradients(zip(gradients, net_params))

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for i in range(100):
             random_input = np.random.rand(10, 10)
             logging.debug('random_input: %s', random_input.__str__())

             sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={inputs: random_input})
             params = sess.run(net_params)
             logging.debug('params: %d' + params.__str__())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case some else encounters the same problem, the solution is to set the gate_gradients flag to True in tf.gradients(). Using this you lose parallelism and performance during the calculation and the application of the gradients to the optimizer, but you gain reproducibility.